# SQL Syntax Error when running through PHP but runs fine as an SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

So, a snippet of my code which is resulting in an error is :

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'notesDB');

if(isset($_POST['tableName'])) {
    $tName = htmlentities($_POST['tableName']);

    $firstQuery = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT into notes(Title) VALUES( '$tName'); CREATE TABLE $tName(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Title varchar(20) NOT NULL, Description varchar(100), PRIMARY KEY(id));");

    if($firstQuery){
        header("Location: create2.php");
    }
    else 
        echo mysqli_error($con);
}
```

The output of this is :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE test1(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Title varchar(20) NOT NULL, D' at line 1
```

Well, the funny thing is that the exact code (except the variable - I just removed the $ sign) executed perfectly in phpMyAdmin.

Also, to prove that there is nothing really wrong with the php, the query executed without any error when it was only the INSERT query (and not the CREATE query).

Comment: "Also, to prove that there is nothing really wrong with the php, the query executed without any error when it was only the INSERT query (and not the CREATE query)." That's not proof that the PHP is correct; it's just proof that the issue with the PHP is the part where you're generating the `CREATE TABLE` part of the SQL.

Comment: You can't run 2 seperate queries in one `mysqli_query` call

Comment: Updated my answer, kindly check it now

Comment: I'm actually a newbie :3
Thanks, though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysqli_query` can only perform one query at a time.

Try [`mysqli_multi_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) instead.

As an aside creating tables on the fly is usually a sign of larger design issues. Schema should be relatively static while data should be dynamic.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
What do you mean by static schema, exactly? I thought by keeping the column names the same across all the tables, the schema would be relatively static.
This was a project to help me understand databases, PHP and SQL so I'm a complete noob.

Comment: I think I understood what you meant. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run two separate queries at a time in the code, which you can't run like that. You have to run them separately like below:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'notesDB');

if(isset($_POST['tableName'])) {
    $tName = htmlentities($_POST['tableName']);

    $firstQuery = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT into notes(Title) VALUES( '$tName')");

$secondQuery = mysqli_query("CREATE        TABLE '$tName' (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Title varchar(20) NOT NULL, Description varchar(100), PRIMARY KEY(id));");

    if($firstQuery || $secondQuery){
        header("Location: create2.php");
    }
    else 
        echo mysqli_error($con);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your database architecture is wrong.
You shouldn't create tables on the fly. So, you have only register whatever new entity with simple regular INSERT query. And then use this entity's id to link records from another [already existing] table.

```
if(isset($_POST['tableName'])) {
    $stm = mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT into notes(Title) VALUES(?)");
    $stm->bind_param("s",$_POST['tableName']);
    $stm->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will do more research on this now!